# executing script in server & displaying continuous output of script in the webpage using Django/python

Tags: python, ajax, django

I have a Django web application running. It has a web page which is a form & it takes few inputs. Then on the execute button it calls a method in my `views.py` & inside that i'm taking the fields entered by user & executes a script in the server which runs for around 1hr. 
Requirement is to show the output of the script to the user in webpage continuously like it would have been if the script was triggered in shell.

Can someone please guide me or point me in right direction on how to achieve this?

Comment: I've never personnaly used it, but there is such a thing as a streaminghttpresponse available in django. That could maybe do the trick:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.StreamingHttpResponse

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [swampdragon](https://github.com/jonashagstedt/swampdragon). It allows you to subscribe to server events via websockets (sockjs). So you should end having something like:

- Django server with Swampdragon sending publish events everytime you want to display something to the clients (new output).
- A js client that subscribes to the swampdragon events/channel to receive them. Everytime you receive a new event, you will need to update the html content with the new data received.

In the swampdragon documentation you have some working examples to test it.

Comment: The script I'm executing in background is tcl script which dumps lots of output to the console. I cannot do any changes to that script. So not sure how will notifications work?

Comment: If you have lots of output in your execution then notifications is not the best approach. Take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.StreamingHttpResponse. I've never used it though.